# Turning data in a data frame column into it's own data frame

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I've been scratching my head for hours. I have some data that I pulled using an API and I turned that into a Data Frame with pandas. I can isolate the column I want to structure into its own DF but I am stuck on how to actually do it. I've searched high and low but there is not an example like this. The data that comes from the API is json if that helps.

so one of the columns is callExpDateMap and the data in it is:

```
{'10.0': [{'putCall': 'CALL', 'symbol': 'MIK_021921C10', 'description': 'MIK Feb 19 2021 10 Call', 'exchangeName': 'OPR', 'bid': 5.5, 'ask': 6.6, 'last': 5.41, 'mark': 6.05, 'bidSize': 36, 'askSize': 36, 'bidAskSize': '36X36', 'lastSize': 0, 'highPrice': 0.0, 'lowPrice': 0.0, 'openPrice': 0.0, 'closePrice': 6.64, 'totalVolume': 0, 'tradeDate': None, 'tradeTimeInLong': 1612471445495, 'quoteTimeInLong': 1613077155694, 'netChange': -1.09, 'volatility': 271.984, 'delta': 0.901, 'gamma': 0.027, 'theta': -0.068, 'vega': 0.004, 'rho': 0.002, 'openInterest': 119, 'timeValue': -0.25, 'theoreticalOptionValue': 6.05, 'theoreticalVolatility': 29.0, 'optionDeliverablesList': None, 'strikePrice': 10.0, 'expirationDate': 1613768400000, 'daysToExpiration': 8, 'expirationType': 'R', 'lastTradingDay': 1613782800000, 'multiplier': 100.0, 'settlementType': ' ', 'deliverableNote': '', 'isIndexOption': None, 'percentChange': -16.42, 'markChange': -0.59, 'markPercentChange': -8.87, 'nonStandard': False, 'inTheMoney': True, 'mini': False}], '12.5': [{'putCall': 'CALL', 'symbol': 'MIK_021921C12.5', 'description': 'MIK Feb 19 2021 12.5 Call', 'exchangeName': 'OPR', 'bid': 1.7, 'ask': 3.4, 'last': 3.6, 'mark': 2.55, 'bidSize': 408, 'askSize': 36, 'bidAskSize': '408X36', 'lastSize': 0, 'highPrice': 4.2, 'lowPrice': 3.6, 'openPrice': 0.0, 'closePrice': 4.19, 'totalVolume': 25, 'tradeDate': None, 'tradeTimeInLong': 1613065348968, 'quoteTimeInLong': 1613077199219, 'netChange': -0.59, 'volatility': 81.53, 'delta': 0.97, 'gamma': 0.036, 'theta': -0.01, 'vega': 0.002, 'rho': 0.003, 'openInterest': 1138, 'timeValue': 0.44, 'theoreticalOptionValue': 3.2, 'theoreticalVolatility': 29.0, 'optionDeliverablesList': None, 'strikePrice': 12.5, 'expirationDate': 1613768400000, 'daysToExpiration': 8, 'expirationType': 'R', 'lastTradingDay': 1613782800000, 'multiplier': 100.0, 'settlementType': ' ', 'deliverableNote': '', 'isIndexOption': None, 'percentChange': -14.04, 'markChange': -1.64, 'markPercentChange': -39.11, 'nonStandard': False, 'inTheMoney': True, 'mini': False}], '15.0': [{'putCall': 'CALL', 'symbol': 'MIK_021921C15', 'description': 'MIK Feb 19 2021 15 Call', 'exchangeName': 'OPR', 'bid': 0.95, 'ask': 1.05, 'last': 1.0, 'mark': 1.0, 'bidSize': 13, 'askSize': 12, 'bidAskSize': '13X12', 'lastSize': 0, 'highPrice': 1.65, 'lowPrice': 0.97, 'openPrice': 0.0, 'closePrice': 1.79, 'totalVolume': 30, 'tradeDate': None, 'tradeTimeInLong': 1613076748160, 'quoteTimeInLong': 1613077199427, 'netChange': -0.79, 'volatility': 64.009, 'delta': 0.691, 'gamma': 0.229, 'theta': -0.033, 'vega': 0.009, 'rho': 0.002, 'openInterest': 3370, 'timeValue': 0.34, 'theoreticalOptionValue': 1.0, 'theoreticalVolatility': 29.0, 'optionDeliverablesList': None, 'strikePrice': 15.0, 'expirationDate': 1613768400000, 'daysToExpiration': 8, 'expirationType': 'R', 'lastTradingDay': 1613782800000, 'multiplier': 100.0, 'settlementType': ' ', 'deliverableNote': '', 'isIndexOption': None, 'percentChange': -44.07, 'markChange': -0.79, 'markPercentChange': -44.07, 'nonStandard': False, 'inTheMoney': True, 'mini': False}], '17.5': [{'putCall': 'CALL', 'symbol': 'MIK_021921C17.5', 'description': 'MIK Feb 19 2021 17.5 Call', 'exchangeName': 'OPR', 'bid': 0.15, 'ask': 0.25, 'last': 0.15, 'mark': 0.2, 'bidSize': 12, 'askSize': 42, 'bidAskSize': '12X42', 'lastSize': 0, 'highPrice': 0.45, 'lowPrice': 0.15, 'openPrice': 0.0, 'closePrice': 0.47, 'totalVolume': 37, 'tradeDate': None, 'tradeTimeInLong': 1613077039645, 'quoteTimeInLong': 1613077173597, 'netChange': -0.32, 'volatility': 78.904, 'delta': 0.199, 'gamma': 0.147, 'theta': -0.031, 'vega': 0.007, 'rho': 0.001, 'openInterest': 2088, 'timeValue': 0.15, 'theoreticalOptionValue': 0.2, 'theoreticalVolatility': 29.0, 'optionDeliverablesList': None, 'strikePrice': 17.5, 'expirationDate': 1613768400000, 'daysToExpiration': 8, 'expirationType': 'R', 'lastTradingDay': 1613782800000, 'multiplier': 100.0, 'settlementType': ' ', 'deliverableNote': '', 'isIndexOption': None, 'percentChange': -68.42, 'markChange': -0.27, 'markPercentChange': -57.89, 'nonStandard': False, 'inTheMoney': False, 'mini': False}], '20.0': [{'putCall': 'CALL', 'symbol': 'MIK_021921C20', 'description': 'MIK Feb 19 2021 20 Call', 'exchangeName': 'OPR', 'bid': 0.0, 'ask': 0.05, 'last': 0.05, 'mark': 0.03, 'bidSize': 0, 'askSize': 28, 'bidAskSize': '0X28', 'lastSize': 0, 'highPrice': 0.15, 'lowPrice': 0.05, 'openPrice': 0.0, 'closePrice': 0.13, 'totalVolume': 306, 'tradeDate': None, 'tradeTimeInLong': 1613076428675, 'quoteTimeInLong': 1613076591127, 'netChange': -0.08, 'volatility': 83.171, 'delta': 0.033, 'gamma': 0.037, 'theta': -0.009, 'vega': 0.002, 'rho': 0.0, 'openInterest': 3015, 'timeValue': 0.05, 'theoreticalOptionValue': 0.025, 'theoreticalVolatility': 29.0, 'optionDeliverablesList': None, 'strikePrice': 20.0, 'expirationDate': 1613768400000, 'daysToExpiration': 8, 'expirationType': 'R', 'lastTradingDay': 1613782800000, 'multiplier': 100.0, 'settlementType': ' ', 'deliverableNote': '', 'isIndexOption': None, 'percentChange': -60.0, 'markChange': -0.1, 'markPercentChange': -80.0, 'nonStandard': False, 'inTheMoney': False, 'mini': False}], '22.5': [{'putCall': 'CALL', 'symbol': 'MIK_021921C22.5', 'description': 'MIK Feb 19 2021 22.5 Call', 'exchangeName': 'OPR', 'bid': 0.0, 'ask': 0.05, 'last': 0.04, 'mark': 0.03, 'bidSize': 0, 'askSize': 1, 'bidAskSize': '0X1', 'lastSize': 0, 'highPrice': 0.05, 'lowPrice': 0.04, 'openPrice': 0.0, 'closePrice': 0.08, 'totalVolume': 31, 'tradeDate': None, 'tradeTimeInLong': 1613072074061, 'quoteTimeInLong': 1613076574089, 'netChange': -0.04, 'volatility': 114.755, 'delta': 0.025, 'gamma': 0.021, 'theta': -0.009, 'vega': 0.001, 'rho': 0.0, 'openInterest': 5484, 'timeValue': 0.04, 'theoreticalOptionValue': 0.025, 'theoreticalVolatility': 29.0, 'optionDeliverablesList': None, 'strikePrice': 22.5, 'expirationDate': 1613768400000, 'daysToExpiration': 8, 'expirationType': 'R', 'lastTradingDay': 1613782800000, 'multiplier': 100.0, 'settlementType': ' ', 'deliverableNote': '', 'isIndexOption': None, 'percentChange': -46.67, 'markChange': -0.05, 'markPercentChange': -66.67, 'nonStandard': False, 'inTheMoney': False, 'mini': False}], '25.0': [{'putCall': 'CALL', 'symbol': 'MIK_021921C25', 'description': 'MIK Feb 19 2021 25 Call', 'exchangeName': 'OPR', 'bid': 0.0, 'ask': 0.1, 'last': 0.05, 'mark': 0.05, 'bidSize': 0, 'askSize': 252, 'bidAskSize': '0X252', 'lastSize': 0, 'highPrice': 0.05, 'lowPrice': 0.05, 'openPrice': 0.0, 'closePrice': 0.05, 'totalVolume': 17, 'tradeDate': None, 'tradeTimeInLong': 1613056533967, 'quoteTimeInLong': 1613077199219, 'netChange': 0.0, 'volatility': 157.63, 'delta': 0.036, 'gamma': 0.021, 'theta': -0.017, 'vega': 0.002, 'rho': 0.0, 'openInterest': 985, 'timeValue': 0.05, 'theoreticalOptionValue': 0.05, 'theoreticalVolatility': 29.0, 'optionDeliverablesList': None, 'strikePrice': 25.0, 'expirationDate': 1613768400000, 'daysToExpiration': 8, 'expirationType': 'R', 'lastTradingDay': 1613782800000, 'multiplier': 100.0, 'settlementType': ' ', 'deliverableNote': '', 'isIndexOption': None, 'percentChange': 0.0, 'markChange': 0.0, 'markPercentChange': 0.0, 'nonStandard': False, 'inTheMoney': False, 'mini': False}]}`
```

What I want is a new DF that looks like

```
    Price    putCall           symbol                descprition...
     10.0       CALL    MIK_021921C10    MIK Feb 19 2021 10 Call...
```

and so on. I just don't know how to iterate through this formatting properly.

Comment: What have you tried, and what went wrong with your attempts? pandas built-in read_json(), json_normalize(), etc?

Comment: With such nested jsons, the trick is to use `pd.json_normalise` with the right record paths.

Comment: I had used json_normalize but not properly I guess. The below answer has gotten me closer. I think the record paths are the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `pd.json_normalise()` with the proper record paths.

1. You want to loop through each of the 'prices' as path and create separate dataframes for each.
2. Append these into a list called `dfs`
3. Then `pd.concat` to create a single dataframe.
4. Finally insert the `prices` column at the start -

```
data = {'10.0': [{'putCall': 'CALL', 'symbol': 'MIK_021921C10', 'description': 'MIK Feb 19 2021 10 Call', 'exchangeName': 'OPR', 'bid': 5.5, 'ask': 6.6, 'last': 5.41, 'mark': 6.05, 'bidSize': 36, 'askSize': 36, 'bidAskSize': '36X36', 'lastSize': 0, 'highPrice': 0.0, 'lowPrice': 0.0, 'openPrice': 0.0, 'closePrice': 6.64, 'totalVolume': 0, 'tradeDate': None, 'tradeTimeInLong': 1612471445495, 'quoteTimeInLong': 1613077155694, 'netChange': -1.09, 'volatility': 271.984, 'delta': 0.901, 'gamma': 0.027, 'theta': -0.068, 'vega': 0.004, 'rho': 0.002, 'openInterest': 119, 'timeValue': -0.25, 'theoreticalOptionValue': 6.05, 'theoreticalVolatility': 29.0, 'optionDeliverablesList': None, 'strikePrice': 10.0, 'expirationDate': 1613768400000, 'daysToExpiration': 8, 'expirationType': 'R', 'lastTradingDay': 1613782800000, 'multiplier': 100.0, 'settlementType': ' ', 'deliverableNote': '', 'isIndexOption': None, 'percentChange': -16.42, 'markChange': -0.59, 'markPercentChange': -8.87, 'nonStandard': False, 'inTheMoney': True, 'mini': False}], '12.5': [{'putCall': 'CALL', 'symbol': 'MIK_021921C12.5', 'description': 'MIK Feb 19 2021 12.5 Call', 'exchangeName': 'OPR', 'bid': 1.7, 'ask': 3.4, 'last': 3.6, 'mark': 2.55, 'bidSize': 408, 'askSize': 36, 'bidAskSize': '408X36', 'lastSize': 0, 'highPrice': 4.2, 'lowPrice': 3.6, 'openPrice': 0.0, 'closePrice': 4.19, 'totalVolume': 25, 'tradeDate': None, 'tradeTimeInLong': 1613065348968, 'quoteTimeInLong': 1613077199219, 'netChange': -0.59, 'volatility': 81.53, 'delta': 0.97, 'gamma': 0.036, 'theta': -0.01, 'vega': 0.002, 'rho': 0.003, 'openInterest': 1138, 'timeValue': 0.44, 'theoreticalOptionValue': 3.2, 'theoreticalVolatility': 29.0, 'optionDeliverablesList': None, 'strikePrice': 12.5, 'expirationDate': 1613768400000, 'daysToExpiration': 8, 'expirationType': 'R', 'lastTradingDay': 1613782800000, 'multiplier': 100.0, 'settlementType': ' ', 'deliverableNote': '', 'isIndexOption': None, 'percentChange': -14.04, 'markChange': -1.64, 'markPercentChange': -39.11, 'nonStandard': False, 'inTheMoney': True, 'mini': False}], '15.0': [{'putCall': 'CALL', 'symbol': 'MIK_021921C15', 'description': 'MIK Feb 19 2021 15 Call', 'exchangeName': 'OPR', 'bid': 0.95, 'ask': 1.05, 'last': 1.0, 'mark': 1.0, 'bidSize': 13, 'askSize': 12, 'bidAskSize': '13X12', 'lastSize': 0, 'highPrice': 1.65, 'lowPrice': 0.97, 'openPrice': 0.0, 'closePrice': 1.79, 'totalVolume': 30, 'tradeDate': None, 'tradeTimeInLong': 1613076748160, 'quoteTimeInLong': 1613077199427, 'netChange': -0.79, 'volatility': 64.009, 'delta': 0.691, 'gamma': 0.229, 'theta': -0.033, 'vega': 0.009, 'rho': 0.002, 'openInterest': 3370, 'timeValue': 0.34, 'theoreticalOptionValue': 1.0, 'theoreticalVolatility': 29.0, 'optionDeliverablesList': None, 'strikePrice': 15.0, 'expirationDate': 1613768400000, 'daysToExpiration': 8, 'expirationType': 'R', 'lastTradingDay': 1613782800000, 'multiplier': 100.0, 'settlementType': ' ', 'deliverableNote': '', 'isIndexOption': None, 'percentChange': -44.07, 'markChange': -0.79, 'markPercentChange': -44.07, 'nonStandard': False, 'inTheMoney': True, 'mini': False}], '17.5': [{'putCall': 'CALL', 'symbol': 'MIK_021921C17.5', 'description': 'MIK Feb 19 2021 17.5 Call', 'exchangeName': 'OPR', 'bid': 0.15, 'ask': 0.25, 'last': 0.15, 'mark': 0.2, 'bidSize': 12, 'askSize': 42, 'bidAskSize': '12X42', 'lastSize': 0, 'highPrice': 0.45, 'lowPrice': 0.15, 'openPrice': 0.0, 'closePrice': 0.47, 'totalVolume': 37, 'tradeDate': None, 'tradeTimeInLong': 1613077039645, 'quoteTimeInLong': 1613077173597, 'netChange': -0.32, 'volatility': 78.904, 'delta': 0.199, 'gamma': 0.147, 'theta': -0.031, 'vega': 0.007, 'rho': 0.001, 'openInterest': 2088, 'timeValue': 0.15, 'theoreticalOptionValue': 0.2, 'theoreticalVolatility': 29.0, 'optionDeliverablesList': None, 'strikePrice': 17.5, 'expirationDate': 1613768400000, 'daysToExpiration': 8, 'expirationType': 'R', 'lastTradingDay': 1613782800000, 'multiplier': 100.0, 'settlementType': ' ', 'deliverableNote': '', 'isIndexOption': None, 'percentChange': -68.42, 'markChange': -0.27, 'markPercentChange': -57.89, 'nonStandard': False, 'inTheMoney': False, 'mini': False}], '20.0': [{'putCall': 'CALL', 'symbol': 'MIK_021921C20', 'description': 'MIK Feb 19 2021 20 Call', 'exchangeName': 'OPR', 'bid': 0.0, 'ask': 0.05, 'last': 0.05, 'mark': 0.03, 'bidSize': 0, 'askSize': 28, 'bidAskSize': '0X28', 'lastSize': 0, 'highPrice': 0.15, 'lowPrice': 0.05, 'openPrice': 0.0, 'closePrice': 0.13, 'totalVolume': 306, 'tradeDate': None, 'tradeTimeInLong': 1613076428675, 'quoteTimeInLong': 1613076591127, 'netChange': -0.08, 'volatility': 83.171, 'delta': 0.033, 'gamma': 0.037, 'theta': -0.009, 'vega': 0.002, 'rho': 0.0, 'openInterest': 3015, 'timeValue': 0.05, 'theoreticalOptionValue': 0.025, 'theoreticalVolatility': 29.0, 'optionDeliverablesList': None, 'strikePrice': 20.0, 'expirationDate': 1613768400000, 'daysToExpiration': 8, 'expirationType': 'R', 'lastTradingDay': 1613782800000, 'multiplier': 100.0, 'settlementType': ' ', 'deliverableNote': '', 'isIndexOption': None, 'percentChange': -60.0, 'markChange': -0.1, 'markPercentChange': -80.0, 'nonStandard': False, 'inTheMoney': False, 'mini': False}], '22.5': [{'putCall': 'CALL', 'symbol': 'MIK_021921C22.5', 'description': 'MIK Feb 19 2021 22.5 Call', 'exchangeName': 'OPR', 'bid': 0.0, 'ask': 0.05, 'last': 0.04, 'mark': 0.03, 'bidSize': 0, 'askSize': 1, 'bidAskSize': '0X1', 'lastSize': 0, 'highPrice': 0.05, 'lowPrice': 0.04, 'openPrice': 0.0, 'closePrice': 0.08, 'totalVolume': 31, 'tradeDate': None, 'tradeTimeInLong': 1613072074061, 'quoteTimeInLong': 1613076574089, 'netChange': -0.04, 'volatility': 114.755, 'delta': 0.025, 'gamma': 0.021, 'theta': -0.009, 'vega': 0.001, 'rho': 0.0, 'openInterest': 5484, 'timeValue': 0.04, 'theoreticalOptionValue': 0.025, 'theoreticalVolatility': 29.0, 'optionDeliverablesList': None, 'strikePrice': 22.5, 'expirationDate': 1613768400000, 'daysToExpiration': 8, 'expirationType': 'R', 'lastTradingDay': 1613782800000, 'multiplier': 100.0, 'settlementType': ' ', 'deliverableNote': '', 'isIndexOption': None, 'percentChange': -46.67, 'markChange': -0.05, 'markPercentChange': -66.67, 'nonStandard': False, 'inTheMoney': False, 'mini': False}], '25.0': [{'putCall': 'CALL', 'symbol': 'MIK_021921C25', 'description': 'MIK Feb 19 2021 25 Call', 'exchangeName': 'OPR', 'bid': 0.0, 'ask': 0.1, 'last': 0.05, 'mark': 0.05, 'bidSize': 0, 'askSize': 252, 'bidAskSize': '0X252', 'lastSize': 0, 'highPrice': 0.05, 'lowPrice': 0.05, 'openPrice': 0.0, 'closePrice': 0.05, 'totalVolume': 17, 'tradeDate': None, 'tradeTimeInLong': 1613056533967, 'quoteTimeInLong': 1613077199219, 'netChange': 0.0, 'volatility': 157.63, 'delta': 0.036, 'gamma': 0.021, 'theta': -0.017, 'vega': 0.002, 'rho': 0.0, 'openInterest': 985, 'timeValue': 0.05, 'theoreticalOptionValue': 0.05, 'theoreticalVolatility': 29.0, 'optionDeliverablesList': None, 'strikePrice': 25.0, 'expirationDate': 1613768400000, 'daysToExpiration': 8, 'expirationType': 'R', 'lastTradingDay': 1613782800000, 'multiplier': 100.0, 'settlementType': ' ', 'deliverableNote': '', 'isIndexOption': None, 'percentChange': 0.0, 'markChange': 0.0, 'markPercentChange': 0.0, 'nonStandard': False, 'inTheMoney': False, 'mini': False}]}

dfs = []

for i in data.keys():
    d = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=i)
    dfs.append(d)

out = pd.concat(dfs)
out.insert(0, 'Price', data.keys())
out
```

[image]

Comment: This has worked somewhat. But the record_path=i causes an error.

has non list value MIK for path symbol. Must be list or null.

Comment: You can modify the for loop to handle edge cases that you face :). Try printing the data.keys() before running the loop for parsing the json. hope this helped!

Comment: I am able to run it for the data that you have shared though. Copied the complete dict as it is.

Comment: Updated my code to add the data variable that I copied and worked for me. Do mark the answer if it helped you and do upvote it if it's well written to your liking. This encourages me to help solve your future questions :)

Comment: I've got it going on the right track. You have been very helpful thank you!

Comment: Glad to help anytime!